# Bigquery "default" client_id in several tools, who or what does it refer to?

Tags: authentication, google-oauth, google-bigquery

I have noticed that in several source codes, applications, a default client_id and a default client_secret are used.
They do work when I connect to my Bigquery projects, (after having authorized the access when prompted in my web browser), but I did not allow any API access to this client_id (well, may be I did by accepting something, but I don't know what...). I don't find this client_id anywhere in the Cloud Console.

Below there's a part of a source code that uses this client_id (and client_secret), which can be found here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/bq/bq.py?r=37103f240562cbe90bbd8df9bd313dcd87b7a106,

```
_CLIENT_INFO = {
'client_id': '977385342095.apps.googleusercontent.com',
'client_secret': 'wbER7576mc_1YOII0dGk7jEE',
'scope': _CLIENT_SCOPE,
'user_agent': _CLIENT_USER_AGENT,
}
```

Does someone know what/who does this client_id refer to please? 
Is it some predefined client_id provided by Google?
And is this client_secret a fixed value that will never change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get an OAuth2 token (for certain types of OAuth), you need three things: a client id, a client secret, and a scope. The first part of the client id is the Google Developer Console Project ID. When you send the OAuth2 token to a backend service, if the backend service has been authorized by the scope, it will be able to crack open the OAuth2 token and extract the Project ID.

In many Google APIs, this is how you specify the project -- implicitly in the OAuth2 token. In BigQuery, however, we want people to be able to use multiple projects without re-authenticating. The project ID is always part of the API request (it is specified in the URL used by all REST API requests). BigQuery doesn't use the project ID derived from the OAuth2 token at all.

But the client id and client secret are still needed. That is why bigquery embeds them in their client tools (bq.py and the web ui). They aren't really secret at all since they are only used to see how popular a particular client is. The alternative would be that each user of bq would have to generate their own client secret / client id, which would make it more difficult to use.

If you're writing code to communicate with BigQuery, we'd prefer that you use your own client id and client secret. They're pretty easy to generate, and they help identify your tool in case of problems.

This is an unfortunate source of confusion, and in the future, we may take steps to fix it, like defaulting the project id used in the request to be the project id from the client id, but currently we have no plans to do so.